# Opencv 3.0 Brisk feature detection with a ROI and Flann matching

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, flann

I have a simple program that uses Brisk detection and flann matching. I'm looking to improve the efficiency by applying the detection to a specific region of interest in each frame. I've tried the following:

```
cv::Mat ROI_scene, scene; 

//region of interest
cv::Rect myROI(10, 10, 100, 100);
cv::Ptr<BRISK> detector = BRISK::create();
cv::Ptr<BRISK> descriptorExtractor = BRISK::create();

while (  capture.read(scene) )
{
    ROI_scene = scene(myROI);
    detector->detect(ROI_scene, keypoints_scene);
    descriptorExtractor->compute(ROI_scene, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene);
    matcher.match(descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches);

}
```

The above returns this error:

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Only continuous arrays are supported) in
>   buildIndex_, file opencv/3.0.0/modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp, line
>   317 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   cv::Exception: opencv/3.0.0/modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp:317:
>   error: (-5) Only continuous arrays are supported in function
>   buildIndex_
>
> Abort trap: 6

I've also tried using copyTO and then I get a Arrays must be 2d or 3d error.

Any insight would be really helpful

Here is a gist of the working code:
https://gist.github.com/DevN00b1/63eba5813926e4d0ea32

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? The error is probably due to something not shown in this piece of code.

Comment: I have updated the post with a gist